# How to merge (append) data from 2 live models?

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 datasets deployed to power bi portal.

On a report I can connect to 1 dataset using live connection, and then convert the connection to DQ to also connect to the 2nd dataset.

Then I can create relationship between the model travels. How to merge (append) data from 2 live models?

Answer (score 1):

Today you can't.

You can leave the tables separate and write DAX measures that operate over both tables.

But if you try creating a DAX calculated table that appends the two, refresh will fail in the service, as this scenario is not currently supported.

Instead of using Direct Query to Power BI Datasets, if the Datasets are on Premium Capacities, you can import tables from both models using the Analysis Services data source and an explicit DAX query.  eg

```
let 
   Source1 = AnalysisServices.Database("powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/someworkspace", "AdventureWorksDW", [Query="evaluate DimCustomer", Implementation="2.0"]),
   Source2 = AnalysisServices.Database("powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/someworkspace", "AdventureWorksDW2", [Query="evaluate DimCustomer", Implementation="2.0"]),
   Appended = Table.Combine({Source1, Source2})
in
    Appended
```

Comment: Is Direct Query to Power BI Datasets a premium capacity only feature?